# innerhtml not print full array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using  innerhtmal for output but the problem is it shows 1 less value the array
I cant find the problem.

[image]

[image]

```js
await fetch(urlbody, bodyrequestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((payload) => {
      console.log(payload)

      payload.map(({
        TRANS_NO,
        TRANS_DATE,
        DR_AMT,
        CR_AMT,
        PARTICULAR
      }, index) => {
        /* Calculatation*/
        oprningbalance += CR_AMT
        oprningbalance -= DR_AMT

        document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML += `<tr>
          <td>${index + 1}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny text-break">${moment(TRANS_DATE).format('LLL')}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${TRANS_NO}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${DR_AMT.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${CR_AMT.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${oprningbalance.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny text-break">${PARTICULAR}</td>
        </tr>`
        total_dr += DR_AMT
        total_cr += CR_AMT
      })
```

Comment: Don't use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set HTML of an existing element.

Comment: @Teemu Why not?

Comment: @mplungjan It's as good as `document.write`, it's wasting time, you're loosing already set event handlers, it's not accepted by several frameworks. The only use for `innerHTML` of an existing element is to make the element empty ...

Comment: I disagree. If you have event handlers you can lose,. then you need to delegate. innerHTML will not bother delegation. What frameworks? You mean React? We do not have React here and even React has a a way to innerHTML which you should not use when you use that framework - also give a better alternative when you are bashing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```js
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = payload.map(({TRANS_NO,TRANS_DATE,DR_AMT,CR_AMT,PARTICULAR}, index) => {
  /* Calculatation*/
  oprningbalance += CR_AMT
  oprningbalance -= DR_AMT
  total_dr += DR_AMT
  total_cr += CR_AMT
  return `<tr>
          <td>${index + 1}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny text-break">${moment(TRANS_DATE).format('LLL')}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${TRANS_NO}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${DR_AMT.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${CR_AMT.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny">${oprningbalance.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td class="text-tiny text-break">${PARTICULAR}</td>
        </tr>`
}).join("")
```